# Do something after .html() has been fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm injecting HTML from another div on the page into a div and then adding a class of .show, like so:

```
var $boxItem = $('.box-grid__item'),
    $htmlData = $($boxItem).find('.box-grid__item-content').html();
$boxItem.click(function () {
    $('.box-grid__item-content-popup').html($htmlData).addClass('show');
});
```

The HTML that gets injected is:

```
<div class="close-btn" aria-label="Close">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
<h2 class="box-grid__item-content-heading">Name and Surname</h2>
<p class="box-grid__item-content-title">Title</p>
<p class="box-grid__item-content-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
```

This works as expected but now I would like to remove the .show. I've tried this but it doesn't fire:

```
$('.close-btn').click(function () {
    $('.box-grid__item-content-popup').removeClass('show');
});
```

Any help will be much appreciated ;)

Comment: I am unbale to see any html element with class `box-grid__item-content-popup`?

Comment: test this code in chrome console: $('.box-grid__item-content-popup').removeClass('show');
if this command work then close-btn onclick don't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are dynamically inserting the HTML, your event handler should be something like:

```
$('.box-grid__item-content-popup').on("click", '.close-btn', function () {
    $('.box-grid__item-content-popup').removeClass('show');
})
```

This means that the events bubbling to `.box-grid__item-content-popup` will be captured, but the handler will fire when the event was triggered on `.close-btn` or one of its descendents.

Ref: See delegated events section at http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thanks very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have your `.click` code before you insert the html.
What you could do, is rewrite your function, so it triggers on the `.box-grid__item` and then put a selector on that.

```
$(".box-grid__item").on("click", ".close-btn", function(){
      $('.box-grid__item-content-popup').removeClass('show');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// create a reference to the old `.html()` function
var htmlOriginal = $.fn.html;

// redefine the `.html()` function to accept a callback
$.fn.html = function(html,callback){
  // run the old `.html()` function with the first parameter
  var ret = htmlOriginal.apply(this, arguments);
  // run the callback (if it is defined)
  if(typeof callback == "function"){
    callback();
  }
  // make sure chaining is not broken
  return ret;
}

// test it all works as expected (including chaining)
$("#mything").html("<div>My Thing</div>",function(){
  console.log("Just did my thing");
}).css({color: 'red'})
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/a49P4/)